# how check overlapse not transparent fragment object in libgdx

Tags: libgdx, transparent

Libgdx.

I have 2 objects: Bucket and drop. 
I use Sprite to manipulation on this objects.

How to check overlapse of non-transparent fragment of objects?

Comment: What exactly do you mean by overlapse of non-transparent fragment? Is it related to collision?

Comment: Sprite had non-transparent fragments and transparent fragments. How check when non-transparent fragment from Bucket overlapse non-transparent fragment of Drop

Comment: I would suggest you to use polygons to mark the non transparent fragments and then use Intersector class of libgdx to check for collision.

Answer (score 0):

I really don't think that there is a function that could handle that.

I use to remove margin that represent the non-transparent of a sprite content

for example if the we put the size of the rectangle that represent the coins like this picture and we ignore the transparent part of the Sprite

[image]

good luck !